# Why close the query later ")"?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have seen a script where the sql query is written as :

```
$Query = "CREATE TABLE something (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, thing TEXT, ddno TEXT";

     #Then normal statements here

#Then the script is closed here
$Query .= ")" ;
```

So why not just close the query above with the right parenthesis ? is there something more one can achieve doing it this way ?

Comment: Umm not unless you want to add more columns..

Comment: Because of `string concatentation`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy i know what is string concatenation just asking why someone will use it when they could have just closed that expression with ")" at the first line

Comment: @user3066913 Bad programming habits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One would do something like that if there are conditional additions to the query:

```
$Query = "CREATE TABLE something (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, thing TEXT, ddno TEXT";

 if ($add_column_x)
 {
   $Query .= ', column_x TEXT';
 }

#Then the script is closed here
$Query .= ")" ;
```